# Laravel 4 Creating Form for adding record with relationship

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4, model

I have created very basic Model. I have persons table and emails table.
Also I have create a link in the `persons/show.blade.php` ("Add mail").
My models are

```
class Person extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'persons';

    public function email()
    {
        return $this->HasMany('Email');
    }

}
```

and

```
class Email extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'emails';

    public static $rules = array(
        'email'=>'required|unique:emails'       
    );

    public function person()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Person');
    }
}
```

How can I pass the `$person->id` to the new Controller?

In my `show.blade.php` for `Person` I added

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute('email.adduseremail','Προσθήκη Email',array($person->id))}}
```

and I added to my EmailController

```
public function adduseremail($id)
{
    return View::make('email.createforuser',['id'=>$id]);
}

public function storeforuser($pid)
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),Email::$rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $messages = $validator->messages();
        foreach ($messages->all('<li>:message</li>') as $message)
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->WithErrors($messages);
    }
    $person = Person::FindorFail($pid);

    $email = new Email;
    $email->email = Input::get('email');
    $email->person()->associate($person);
    $email->save();

    return Redirect::route('person.index');
}
```

and my `createforuser` view is

```
<p>
{{Form::open(['route'=>'email.storeforuser'])}}
<div>
    {{Form::label('email', 'Email:')}}  
    {{Form::input('text', 'email')}}
    {{$errors->first('email')}}
</div>
</br>
<div>
{{Form::submit('Submit')}}
</div>
{{Form::close()}}
<p>
```

I keep getting Trying to get property of non-object (View: `/var/www/laravel/app/views/email/show.blade.php`)

Is there any example using Form and Models for inserting new objects to the database for 'belongsTo' Relationship? I couldn't find anything complete , just partial examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally use laravel sessions or laravel cache to tempererally save an id that i need to use later like:
    Session::set('personId',$person->id);
    Session::get('personId');

The same is for cache except cache will only last for the current request session is persistent for the session 
Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, i implement your suggestion finally because my way (see below)I faced problems when validation failed and had to redirect to a post route

Answer (score 0):

I am no sure if I 'm supposed to answer my own question but finally I found a solution. 
I set two new routes

```
Route::post('email/adduseremail/{pid}', array('uses'=>'EmailController@adduseremail','as' => 'email.adduseremail'));
Route::post('email/storeforuser/{pid}', array('uses' =>'EmailController@storeforuser','as' => 'email.storeforuser'));
```

and created the corresponding methods in my Controller

```
public function adduseremail($id)
{
$pname = Person::Find($id)->name;
$psurname = Person::Find($id)->surname;

return View::make('email.createforuser',array('id'=>$id,'name'=>$pname, 'surname'=>$psurname));
}
```

and

```
public function storeforuser($pid)
{
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),Email::$rules);
if ($validator->fails())
    {
    $messages = $validator->messages();
    foreach ($messages->all('<li>:message</li>') as $message)
    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->WithErrors($messages);
    }
    $person = Person::FindorFail($pid);
    $email = new Email;
    $email->email = Input::get('email');
    $email->person()->associate($person);
    $email->save();

    return Redirect::route('person.show',array($person->id));

}
```

then on my view blade pages I can pass the parameters from View to Form and so on

```
person.show.blade.php


{{Form::Open(array('route' => array('email.adduseremail', $person->id),'method' => 'POST','style'=>'display:inline;'))}}
{{Form::submit('Add Email')}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

and

```
email.createforuser.blade.php

{{Form::open(array('route'=>array('email.storeforuser',$id),'method' => 'POST','style'=>'display:inline;'))}}
{{Form::label('email', 'Email:')}}  
    {{Form::input('text', 'email')}}
    {{Form::submit('Submit')}}
```

Hope it helps others also